# CM 10.2 with Google Apps version 20130813 won't download from Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a Galaxy S3 I9300 from Telcel, Mexico running CyanogenMod 10.2.0, upgraded from 10.1.3 with the upgrade feature and using TWRP for this purpose. I am unable to download anything from the Play Store, the store loads but the apps won't download. I have flashed the gapps-20130813 package, cleared data and uninstalled updates from Play Store and Google Play Services, and it won't download yet. After googling around, I already cleared data on Google Play, Google Framework and Google Play Services, every single cache with Titanium Backup, cleaned up Dalvik cache, and removed and re-added my Google account. Still no luck.

I also noticed the download notification briefly appearing for a split second when I tap Download on Google Play.

Is there anything I can't do? I don't want to go through the hassle of backing everything up, deleting the entire data partition and restoring everything.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include the *exact* name of the GApps file you flashed? It's just a guess, but you might have picked the wrong one. It must match your CM version (see [CM Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Gapps)). Though, the date suggests you've got the correct one; the one for 10.1 is "20130812".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry buddy. Factory reset does the trick... usually this is required when switching between ROM versions, and the Gapps XDA page mentions also that to flash a new Gapps you need to format the /system partition, data, and dalvik.

Comment: You absolutely do not have to format /system. (I flash ROMs and GApps  on devices regularly). You go into recovery and flash the GApps package, then wipe cache and dalvik-cache. Only the ROMs need the /system wiped, which if you look during flashing will show the /system getting wiped.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to go through the hassle of backing everything up,
>   deleting the entire data partition and restoring everything.

That might appear as a very long process to do, but what if that actually is all what you might need to do?

Well, I guess the problem you are facing might be similar to what I've experienced some time ago, and below are the steps I took:

- Sign out of all Google Accounts on device
- Boot Into Recovery (cwm/twrp, whichever)
- Wipe Cache/Dalvik
- Reinstall/Flash CyanogenMod (a nightly known to work)
- Reinstall/Flash GApps (a correct version for your CM)
- Reboot
- Sign into Google account (log into default google account first, assuming you've got multiple accounts you log into)
- Open Google Search
- Enter Google Play Services
- Click on the link to the app in Play Store
- If need be, Update it (if it doesn't update, do below)
- Open Play Store
- Important: Still connected to internet, leave Play Store open for sometime (depending on internet connection). Sometimes, Play Store    prevents any download of apps, UNTIL the Play Store app is up to    latest version. Any attempt to install something during that period    will be futile)
- Confirm Play Store app is up to latest. Check the version number and compare to latest play store apk on, say, APKmirror.com
- If app version is latest, go ahead to update Google Play Services following steps above
- If that works, go ahead to try downloading an app.
- Are you on a Good internet connection?
- If all doesn't work, then, how about you clean install your CM again?

You might not like my last point, but if that's what will get your phone working smoothly again, why the hesitation?